# ¿Como evitar que me imprima basura de un arreglo?

Tags: c, array

Mi programa leé un texto de un .txt y lo guarda en el arreglo **texto[TAMTEXTO]** carácter por carácter luego en la funcion **separarPalabras();** separo las palabras con una condición **if**,si encuentra un espacio guarda las palabra en un arreglo bídimensional **palabra[NUMPALABRAS][30]** además agregue en el **else** una condicion para que cuando encuentre el espacio llene el resto del array con un \0 ó fin de cadena, esto se ejecuta hasta que se acaba el texto, el problema es que al mandar a imprimir el arreglo bidimensional que guarda mis palabras imprime basura al principio y al final pues ya que en el .txt al principio del texto y al final no hay un espacio, *¿Que condicion podria agregar para que no imprima esa basura?*

```
void separarPalabras(char texto[TAMTEXTO],char palabra[NUMPALABRAS][30])
{
    int i;
    int posicionLetra = 0;
    int posicionPalabra = 0;

    for(i = 0; i<TAMTEXTO; i++)
    {
        if(texto[i] != ' '&& texto[i] )
        {
            palabra[posicionPalabra][posicionLetra] = texto[i];
            posicionLetra++;
        }
        else
        {
            palabra[posicionPalabra][posicionLetra]= '\0';
            posicionLetra =0;
            posicionPalabra++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Antes de empezar a llenar tu matriz con palabras inicializala con `\0`, por ejemplo:

```
palabra[10][50] = {{'\0'}};
```

Comment: +1 Estaba a punto de escribir la respuesta usando usando ciclos anidados, pero desistí una vez vi cargada esta participación. puesto que claramente es mucho mas simple y atañe perfectamente a la solución del problema.

Comment: Este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597491/5622844) puede ser de utilidad.